# List files/folders whose name represents a date greater than

Tags: sorting, date

In a "backup" folder, where most subfolders are named with a date, like in the following example:

```
backup/
    20190401/
    (...)
    20190429/
```

I want to list all folders whose name are dates greater than, let's say, "20190415".

The point here is that the naming format allows sorting names in alphanumeric order to get a date sorting, so I guess something should be done with sorting order and criteria, but what?

Thank you!

Comment: With this date format it doesn't matter: lexicographic and numeric comparisons will give the same result.

Comment: Sure. However, I'm looking to find a command to compare filenames together. 20190415 < 20190429

Comment: The `if` command will do this: the precise syntax will depend on the OS and shell.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu with bash. I tried with `if [ ${name1} -gt ${name2} ]` with no result

Comment: What do you mean by "with no result"? There is always a result, true or false. If there are other characters in the directory (such as trailing `/`) then you'll need to use lexicographic comparison `if [ "${name1}" ">" "${name2}" ]`. The quotes round the `>` are needed for correct parsing, but it is good practice to use them in variable expansions.